# Entity Framework/Web API: How do I return combined results of multiple stored procedure calls?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, asp.net-web-api

Okay, I know my question may sound like something that has been asked many many times before, but this is slightly different.  At least I could not find the same question (but a lot of similar, but not quite the same, questions).

I am NOT asking how to work with multiple results from a stored procedure call, nor how to call multiple stored procedures.

What I would like to know is... **How do I call a stored procedure multiple times, combine the result from each call, and return the combined result with Entity Framework/Web API??**

===

(The below are more details on what I want to do, why I want to do it, what I have tried, and code samples)

I have a OData web service, which has a function (action), which calls a stored procedure.  Since a web service call is a relatively expensive operation, I want to allow users to make one web service call, which will call the stored procedure multiple times for the user and return a (combined) results.

Here's a function in my Controller class, for a single web service call for a single stored procedure invocation scenario.  It works out fine.

```
    public IHttpActionResult GetMorgagetDetail(ODataActionParameters parameters)
    {
        // Set up the parameters for the stored procedure
        SqlParameter[] sqlparams;
        sqlparams = new SqlParameter[2];

        sqlparams[0] = new SqlParameter("@Name", System.Data.SqlDbType.Char, 10);
        sqlparams[0].Value = parameters["Name"].ToString();

        sqlparams[1] = new SqlParameter("@Address", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
        sqlparams[1].Value = parameters["Address"].ToString();

        // Call the stored procedure
        var result = this.context.Database.SqlQuery<Entities.MortgateDetail>("dbo.sp_GetMortgageDetail @Name, @Address", sqlparams);

        return Ok(result);
    }
```

Like I said, however, I would like to enable users to pass in multiple values in one of the parameters (Address in this case) and have the web service function call the same stored procedure, but multiple times with a different Address value for each call.  Here's an implementation I tried and am having an issue with:

```
    public IHttpActionResult GetMultipleMorgagetDetail(ODataActionParameters parameters)
    {
        var response = new List<Entities.MortgateDetail>();

        // Set up the parameters for the stored procedure
        SqlParameter[] sqlparams;
        sqlparams = new SqlParameter[2];

        sqlparams[0] = new SqlParameter("@Name", System.Data.SqlDbType.Char, 10);
        sqlparams[0].Value = parameters["Name"].ToString();

        sqlparams[1] = new SqlParameter("@Address", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);

        var addresses = parameters["Addresses"] as IEnumerable<string>;
        foreach (string address in addresses)
        {
            sqlparams[1].Value = address;
            var result = this.context.Database.SqlQuery<Entities.MortgateDetail>("dbo.sp_GetMortgageDetail @Name, @Address", sqlparams);

            response.Add(result.FirstOrDefault<Entities.MortgateDetail>());
        }

        return Ok(response);
    }
```

What I am trying to do is to get a single row (First or Default - the sp will always return only one row, by the way) from the returned result, and add that to a List that I created (of type Entities.MortgateDetail).  And I am doing this in iterations, so I get a single row for each iteration (each call) and add it to my List colleciton, and then once I'm done with the iteration I would return the List.

For whatever reason, it seems like it does not want to get a single row from the returned result and add it to my List.  I don't know what I am doing wrong here...  I obviously tried a many different variations.. and among them I had the code just return a single row from the result like following:

```
    public IHttpActionResult GetMultipleMorgagetDetail(ODataActionParameters parameters)
    {
        // Set up the parameters for the stored procedure
        SqlParameter[] sqlparams;
        sqlparams = new SqlParameter[2];

        sqlparams[0] = new SqlParameter("@Name", System.Data.SqlDbType.Char, 10);
        sqlparams[0].Value = parameters["Name"].ToString();

        sqlparams[1] = new SqlParameter("@Address", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);

        var addresses = parameters["Addresses"] as IEnumerable<string>;
        foreach (string name in addresses)
        {
            sqlparams[1].Value = name;
            var result = this.context.Database.SqlQuery<Entities.MortgateDetail>("dbo.sp_GetMortgageDetail @Name, @Address", sqlparams);

            return Ok(result.FirstOrDefault());
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

And, it worked okay.  Well, obviously not what I want to do (and I don't think the code makes much sense, either), but nonetheless it didn't throw any runtime error.  So, it's as if "result.FirstOrDefault()" will give me an error anywhere else but when it's used for returning a value from the method...

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

==========================================

UPDATES:

This is reqlly werid...  After a little more investigation, I've found out that the error is thrown when it tries to call "Database.SqlQuery()" more than once.

So, as long as I only call the sp once, then everything is okay.  However, the second time I am trying to call the sp, it craps out :(

The following code will throw an error.  On SQL Profiler, I will only see one sp call:

```
    public IHttpActionResult GetMorgagetDetail(ODataActionParameters parameters)
    {
        // Set up the parameters for the stored procedure
        SqlParameter[] sqlparams;
        sqlparams = new SqlParameter[2];

        sqlparams[0] = new SqlParameter("@Name", System.Data.SqlDbType.Char, 10);
        sqlparams[0].Value = parameters["Name"].ToString();

        sqlparams[1] = new SqlParameter("@Address", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
        sqlparams[1].Value = parameters["Address"].ToString();

        // Call the stored procedure twice
        var result = this.context.Database.SqlQuery<Entities.MortgateDetail>("dbo.sp_GetMortgageDetail @Name, @Address", sqlparams);
        result = this.context.Database.SqlQuery<Entities.MortgateDetail>("dbo.sp_GetMortgageDetail @Name, @Address", sqlparams);

        return Ok(result);
    }
```

I think the sp is not actually called when I am calling it, but the framework does some kind of queueing the sp call and calls it when it thinks is the best time to do it or something, and while it's doing that it screws up something and as a result I cannot make two (or multiple) successive calls to the same sp right after one another....

I know none of this makes much sense, but I really don't see logical flaw in my code.  I am not going to share all the different variations of the code I tried during my investigation, but at one point I hard-coded everything and made my routine just call the sp back to back, and it crapped out.

One interesting observation I had was, when calling the sp twice, if I use to separate variables for the result (say result1 and result2), and only return one of the variables ("return Ok(result1);"  or "return Ok(result2);") then no error is thrown.  However, on the Profiler, I can see only one sp call was made, which was for the result that my function returned.

In other words, even though I had a line that calls the sp and assigns the returned result to a variale in my code, that actually doesn't get executed (all the way to actually calling the sp), unless my code actually uses the result (i.e. returning it).  That's why I suspect the framework does some kind of traffic controlling and decides when to inovke the sp on the backend... which apparently has some bug.

I tried to find if there's a way to force the framework to commit the database transaction (= sp calling), or flushing out the results so that the second time calling the same sp will be just like calling it for the first time, I could not find anything.

Argggggg

Comment: Have you confirmed that `parameters["Addresses"] as IEnumerable<string>;` does in fact contain more than one address?

Comment: have you tried debugging the foreach loop step by step? It appears that parameters["Addresses"] has just 1 item. Debugging should help clarify that.

Comment: Brendan Green & Hopeless,

Comment: Brendan Green & Hopeless,

First of all, thanks for youre reply.  

Yes, that collection parameter does contain more than one address.  I tried to append all the passed in addresses into a string in each iteration, and throw that string as an exception after the loop is complete.  I was able to confirm all, multiple values got passed in okay in a collection.

I had to use some framework which my company requires everyone to use (it's like an extension of EF and Web API), which has a lot of late bindings and stuff that are going on behind the scene, which also makes the debugger uesless... :(

Comment: Is the last iteration trying to add null to your collection by any chance?

Comment: Also, can you explain what is not working, exactly? I understand your expected result, but not what you are seeing at the moment.

Comment: ESG,

First of all, I believe it's not trying to add null at the end of the iteration.  LIke mentioned, I tried to display all the parameters in an exception message, and I was able to see all the parameter values (which were added to the exception message through iteration). 

Also, I am monitoring the database when running this code with Profiler, and I only see one query with the first parameter coming in.  In other words, it seems like the there's an error right after the first call to the sp.

Well, I do get some sort of Null reference error... :(

Comment: Thanks to the framework I'm foreced to use, I unfortunately cannot get much info from the debugger - the debugger always takes me to the same line in the exception hanlding routine, no matter what the actual excpetion was...  It looks as if the actual calling of the sp and getting the data back is being done in some library of which the source code is not available for the debugger.